# String parameter nullable generate wrong sql query

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

I migrate a project from ef core 2.2.6 to 3.0.1.

My project use C# 8.0 and enable nullable like that :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I corrected many issues and deliver to in production, but performances are downgraded.
The I/O are become more important than before.

I created a repo with the following sample for ef core 2.2.6 and 3.0.1 :
https://github.com/reservoir-dogs/EFCore3CSharp8

I have an entity like that :

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Required { get; set; }

    public string? Nullable { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute, the following queries :

```cs
var message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Id == 123).FirstOrDefault();
message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Required == "123").FirstOrDefault();
message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Nullable == "123").FirstOrDefault();

long id = 123;
string code = "123";
message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Required == code).FirstOrDefault();
message = applicationDbContext.Foos.Where(s => s.Nullable == code).FirstOrDefault();
```

In 2.2.6, I had this log

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (56ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [s].[Id], [s].[Nullable], [s].[Required]
FROM [Foos] AS [s]
    WHERE [s].[Id] = CAST(123 AS bigint)
... WHERE [s].[Required] = N'123'
... WHERE [s].[Nullable] = N'123'
... WHERE [s].[Id] = @__id_0
... WHERE [s].[Required] = @__code_0
... WHERE [s].[Nullable] = @__code_0
```

Now, I have this :

```
... WHERE [f].[Id] = CAST(123 AS bigint)
... WHERE [f].[Required] = N'123'
... WHERE ([f].[Nullable] = N'123') **AND [f].[Nullable] IS NOT NULL**
... WHERE ([f].[Id] = @__id_0) **AND @__id_0 IS NOT NULL**
... WHERE ([f].[Required] = @__code_0) **AND @__code_0 IS NOT NULL**
... WHERE (([f].[Nullable] = @__code_0) AND ([f].[Nullable] IS NOT NULL **AND @__code_0 IS NOT NULL)) OR ([f].[Nullable] IS NULL AND @__code_0 IS NULL)**
```

EF do a bad interpretation any variables in lambdas expressions about type of string not nullable and add useless parameters which modify the execution plan.

How to write the old syntax sql query with last version ef core ?
Why EF Core 3.0 in a C# 8.0 context, do it check the nullability of parameters which can't to be ?

Comment: WHat's the difference? Don't force people to diff the two snippets just to find the differences. `([f].[Nullable] = N'123') AND [f].[Nullable] IS NOT NULL` will be simplified to `[f].[Nullable] = N'123'` though and won't affect the execution plan

Comment: Assuming I read those too-long strings correctly, only the last query shows any difference and it's actually *correct*. If `@code` is null, the only way to match null 
 `Nullable` values is to use `Nullable IS NULL and @code IS NULL`. EF Core 2.2.6 would have to either lose results, or create a different query if `code` was null

Comment: Definitely something is broken in 3.0. Consider searching/reporting in their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You have reason. The execution plan is same and even the times are better with clause 'OR'. 
https://imgur.com/a/M5m1Rqo . My issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Seems like 1) this was already [reported by Julie Lerman](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18733) which is very good and 2) the daily preview 3.1.0-preview3.19553.2  doesn't seem to generate extra null checks. The latest NuGet package is 3.1.0-preview3.19554.8 so the problem *may* be fixed already

Comment: Can you try the [latest 3.1 Preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.0-preview3.19554.8) ? Is the problem still there? [EF Core is covered by .NET Core's](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) LTS policy so the real long-term support version of EF Core 3 will be 3.1